# divide by zero encountered in true_divide + invalid value encountered in true_divide + invalid value encountered in reduce

Tags: python, numpy, divide-by-zero

Here is what I've tried to plot a semi-[Planck law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) based on the variations of temperature and distance as follows.

```
import numpy as np

k = 1.381*np.power(10,-23, dtype=np.float)
c = 3*np.power(10,8)
h = 6.626*np.power(10,-34, dtype=np.float)  
l = 3*np.power(10,-6, dtype=np.float)

d_lower = 16*np.power(10,4)
d_upper = 2*np.power(10,6)

t_lower = 740
t_upper = 5200

d = np.arange(d_lower,d_upper,100)
t = np.arange(t_lower,t_upper,10)
D,T = np.meshgrid(d, t)
I = (2*h*np.power(c,2))/(np.power(D,2)*np.power(l,5)*(np.exp((h*c)/(l*k*T))-1))
```

The interpreter returns the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  I = (2*h*np.power(c,2))/(np.power(D,2)*np.power(l,5)*(np.exp((h*c)/(l*k*T))-1))
```

I shouldn't have been encountered any divide-by-zero since the `T` values are in Kelvin, so `np.exp((h*c)/(l*k*T))-1` can't become zero.

What is wrong here?!

My python and numpy versions are `3.7.0` and `1.15.4`, respectively.

Comment: The code works fine for me without any warnings or error producing a different plot (not sure if it is what you want). I am using matplotlib 2.2.2 and python 3.6.5. What version do you use?

Comment: @Bazingaa: My python is `3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)]`, and my matplotlib is `3.0.2`.

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/xCRMhzP) is what I am getting

Comment: @Bazingaa: It pretty makes sense. But it's strange that I can't generate it!

Comment: I also plotted `(np.exp((h*c)/(l*k*T))-1)` versus `t` and saw that the 1-d curve has an asymptote at around 1.5. So, yes the value doesn't reach 0. No idea what's up

Comment: I removed matplotlib from the question, since this is purely a numpy issue. You might report your numpy version.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: My numpy version is `1.15.4`.

Comment: The problem seems to be solved by using a float array, `d = np.arange(d_lower,d_upper,100.)` (`d.dtype == float64`) instead of an integer array `d = np.arange(d_lower,d_upper,100)` (`d.dtype == int32`). I currently don't know why that causes the issue.

Comment: Presumably you are on a platform (probably Windows) where the default data type for a numpy integer array is 32 bit (`np.int32`).  The expressions `np.power(D, 2)` is computed using the data type of `D`, so its result has type `np.int32`.  However, the exact values in that result are larger than can be represented with 32 bit integers, so the values overflow and may become negative or zero.  For example, `np.array([106000, 1638400], dtype=np.int32)**2` returns `array([-1648901888,           0], dtype=int32)`.  @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's suggestion to use floating point will fix the problem.

Comment: P.S., FYI: An expression such as `1.381*np.power(10,-23, dtype=np.float)` can be more conventionally and conveniently written `1.381e-23`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem comes maybe from the fact that it is a matrix division and python doesn't handle it so well.

Try to replace :

I = (2*h*np.power(c,2))/(np.power(D,2)*np.power(l,5)*(np.exp((h*c)/(l*k*T))-1))

by :

```
aaa = (2*h*np.power(c,2))
bbb = (np.power(D,2)*np.power(l,5)*(np.exp((h*c)/(l*k*T))-1))  
I = aaa/bbb
```

It worked for me

SLP